# Rewrite Rule in Nginx to Block a Specific URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I would like to block a specific URL from being access and return a 444 Error.

Example:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ https://subdomain.domain.com/abc/xyzdirector/login.do ) {
return    444;
}
```

Now this works fine, the issue is if I type the following URL in my browser and change ANY of the capitalization in the sub-directories, it does not work:

Example:

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/ABC/xyzdirector/login.d
https://subdomain.domain.com/abc/XYZdirector/login.d
https://subdomain.domain.com/abc/xyzdirecTOR/login.d
https://subdomain.domain.com/Abc/XyzDirector/login.d
```

When I do this, the url gets forwarded and servered.

How do I block this?

Answer (score 4):

You want a case-insensitive [regex location](http://nginx.org/r/location):

```
location ~* ^/abc/xyzdirector/login\.do$ {
  return 444;
}
```

If you have any other regex locations in your config, make sure you put this one above any others that may match this url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was perfect and worked like a charm. Apologies for replying late.